# How to merge multiple columns into 1 indicator by using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data set:

```
Class   2000    2001    2002    2003
A   1   2   3   4
B   5   5   4   4
C   2   1   5   6
```

And I want to have the result like this:

```
Class   Year    Value
A   2000    1
A   2001    2
A   2002    3
A   2003    4
B   2000    5
B   2001    5
B   2002    4
B   2003    4
C   2000    2
C   2001    1
C   2002    5
C   2003    6
```

Please help me!

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! You should know that StackOverflow is not for others to write code for you but instead to get help based on what you already did. If you have some code you wrote, you can edit your post to add it. It will be very helpful for the people here to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to un-pivot the DataFrame, in Pandas they call it 'pandas.melt' [[link]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

For your example:

```
pandas.melt(df, id_vars=['Class'], value_vars=['2000','2001','2002','2003'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) along with [sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Since doing `sort_values()` jumbles up the index, you [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the column

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d = '''Class   2000    2001    2002    2003
A   1   2   3   4
B   5   5   4   4
C   2   1   5   6'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Class'], value_vars=['2000','2001','2002','2003']).sort_values(by=['Class'])
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'variable':'Year'})
print(df2)

# output
  Class  Year  value
0      A  2000      1
1      A  2001      2
2      A  2002      3
3      A  2003      4
4      B  2000      5
5      B  2001      5
6      B  2002      4
7      B  2003      4
8      C  2000      2
9      C  2001      1
10     C  2002      5
11     C  2003      6
```

Link for doing check online: [Online Check](https://repl.it/repls/PertinentThankfulRatio)

Answer (score 1):

I created it in a method chain with a pandas feature.

```
df = df.set_index('Class').unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Year', 0:'Value'}).sort_values(['Class','Year']).reset_index(drop=True)

df
Year    Class   Value
0   2000    A   1
1   2001    A   2
2   2002    A   3
3   2003    A   4
4   2000    B   5
5   2001    B   5
6   2002    B   4
7   2003    B   4
8   2000    C   2
9   2001    C   1
10  2002    C   5
11  2003    C   6
```